# Accessing database information inside a loop and storing outside

Tags: java, mysql, scope

The issue is definitely within the scope but, I am having issues figuring out why since I declared the variables that are storing the information outside the loop

```
public Member searchMember (String email) {

    int Sid = 0;
    String name ="";
    String adr = "";
    String phone = "";
    String email2 = "";
    String pass = "";
    boolean status =false;
    Member a = new Member(name,adr,phone,email2,pass);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://compsi:3306/mcrowley","mcrowley","700463874");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        System.out.println(email);
        String query = "Select id,name,address,phoneNum,email,password,LoginStatus From member WHERE email Like '%"+email+"%' ";
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Before while loop");
        int count = 0;
        while (results.next() || count == 0 ) { 
            if (count == 0)
            results.absolute(1);

            System.out.println("Start while loop");
            Sid = results.getInt(1);
            //System.out.println(Sid+" this is test in jdbc");
            name = results.getString(2);
            //System.out.println(name+" this is test in jdbc");
            adr = results.getString("address");
            phone = results.getString("phoneNum");
            email2 = results.getString("email");
            pass = results.getString("password");
            int stat = results.getInt("loginStatus");
            if (stat == 0) {
                status = false;
            }
            else {
                status = true;
          }
            count++;
            if (!results.next()) {
                a.setName(name);
                a.setAddress(adr);
                a.setPhoneNumber(phone);
                a.setEmail(email2);
                a.setPassword(pass);
                a.setId(Sid);
                a.setStatus(status);
                return a;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("After while loop");
        a.setName(name);
        a.setAddress(adr);
        a.setPhoneNumber(phone);
        a.setEmail(email2);
        a.setPassword(pass);
        a.setId(Sid);
        a.setStatus(status);
        //create object & print 
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        return a;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? please specify it....

Answer (score 0):

So basically it sounds like you need a refresher course about [the scope of variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3).

Essentially, you're not coming here with *broken* code that you want to know how to fix.  But instead you're being rolling because you think it ought *not* to work.

Here's how I remember it: every scope has access to variables declared in itself as well as the scope that is its direct parent.  That is, the parent scope can't read and modify any of its soon-to-be cheers.

So basically, the answer to your question is that your intuition is incorrect.  Variable scope doesn't function in the way you thought it did.